# 70s? Two or three short stories involving the discovery of a time sensitive molecule/compound/substance

Tags: short-stories, time-travel, story-identification

The first story was written almost as a scientific paper reporting the discovery of a time sensitive substance. It described the theory, and process that led to its discovery and include charts and graphs.

Basically, they noted that Ammonia *[not the compounds in the stories, just an example]* NH₄ dissolves in water in 5 seconds. And that Benzene C₆H₆ dissolves in 3 seconds and that Butane C₄H₁₀ dissolves in 1 second. And they proposed that a substance with more H atoms would dissolve even faster.  They find a substance with, for example, XxH₂₄ that would dissolve a second or two **Before** the water was added.

I think that this **only** occurred with the mechanical addition of the water, (no human involvement, for example on a timer) **or** if the human committed to pouring the water mentally. If there was the slightest chance that he might **not** pour it, the reaction would not take place until the water made contact.

I am unsure what the second story involved, maybe it involved the testing to see possible results of trying to "game the system" to make the substance dissolve without the water being added. (for instance, cutting the power to the valve just before the time reaches zero)

The 3rd (or later?) story was set 20? 30? 50? years in the future, set in a college classroom? or Lecture hall? where they are discussing the use of the substance to facilitate time travel? Or how it might be used to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be thinking of the [thiotimoline series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?24318) by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267468/story-about-reaction-with-water-that-must-proceed-ending-with-hurricane). Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiotimoline):

> **Thiotimoline** is a fictitious chemical compound conceived by American biochemist and science fiction author Isaac Asimov. It was first described in a spoof scientific paper titled "The Endochronic Properties of Resublimated Thiotimoline" in 1948. The major peculiarity of the chemical is its "endochronicity": it starts dissolving before it makes contact with water.
>
> Asimov went on to write three additional short stories, each describing different properties or uses of thiotimoline.

Links below are to the Internet Archive.

["The Endochronic Properties of Resublimated Thiotimoline", *Astounding Science Fiction*, March 1948](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v41n01_1948-03_UnkSc-cape1736/page/n119/mode/2up)
["The Micropsychiatric Applications of Thiotimoline", *Astounding Science Fiction*, December 1953](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v52n04_1953-12_dtsg0318/page/n105/mode/2up)
["Thiotimoline and the Space Age", *Analog Science Fact -> Fiction*, October 1960](https://archive.org/details/sim_analog-science-fiction-fact_1960-10_66_2/page/154/mode/2up)
["Thiotimoline to the Stars", *Astounding John W. Campbell Memorial Anthology*, 1973](https://archive.org/details/astoundingjohnwc00camp)

Comment: Yes that is it!!